# FacebookAPIで友人のウォール情報取得

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FacebookAPIについて質問です。

API経由で友人のウォールの投稿を取得することは可能でしょうか？

色々調べて、FacebookページやGroupの情報は取得できるみたいだと思うのですが、個人アカウント(友達)のウォール情報が取れるのかどうか分かりませんでした。

APIを調べていたら、昔はAPI経由で友人のウォールに投稿することは出来たけど現在は出来なくなっているみたいな記事もありました。 
http://facebook-docs.oklahome.net/archives/52072855.html

このあたりの仕様に詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします!

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed
が基本となります。友人のuser_idを取得して、個々に取得してはどうでしょうか。

APIを調べるのであれば。公式のドキュメントのほうが好ましいと思うのですが……。
もし/feedで対応できないことをしたいのであれば。その事例を質問に追加してもらえますでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

/{user-id}/feedで自分自身やFBページのIDを指定した場合は情報が取れるのですが、友人のユーザIDを指定しても取得できませんでした。

/feedで対応出来るのでしょうか?

![](http://i.gyazo.com/ccae7af3a792afa8b75585b5f6b1ec6c.png)

Comment: 試しに開発用のアカウントに切り替えて、自分のフィード(つまり第三者のフィード)をgraphtoolから取得できました(当然、公開範囲が合致する範囲だけなので、再度切り替えて、公開設定を閉じて、再び戻って同じことしたら見れなくなった事も確認しました)。

http://gyazo.com/99075d1e48cff1540e2d26ea14e23c90